# How to disable print statements if a file size is over 1GB?

Tags: c++, printing

So, let's just say I'm transferring a file over a socket to a client. I want a definition that suppresses `cout` and `printf` if activated.

So, for example:

```
#define SURPRESS
:
ifdef SURPRESS
    // surpresses cout and printf
endif
```

If I detect that the file size is over 1GB, the program would automatically call the definition `SURPRESS` and surpress all cout and print statements.

Would something like the above example work?

Comment: Would not work. If the file-size is not known at compile time, but only at runtime, you have to use an `if`-statement or other conditional to pick the right behavior. Macros (`#define`) are expanded before compilation.

Comment: Nope use a if statement. If you have cout's all over your code you can simple change the buffer cout writes too a NULL buffer. This will supress output. Recommend is to save the original buffer to later bind cout back.